# Recursive saddleback - searching for an element in sorted 2D array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I'm coding saddleback search in a sorted 2D array in Java and weird things happen.

Algorithm has to find the first occurence of given `k` element in an array (rows first, then columns). Then it should also show on which index given number was found.

I wrote saddleback algorithm iteratively and it works, but after recoding it as recursive - it does not.

For array

`10 10 10 10
 10 20 20 30
 20 20 20 40`

And `k: 20`

It outputs, that k cannot be found in given array.

Also - the algorithm has got to have lower complexity than O(n,m)^3, so any other algorithm tips will be apprecieated.

Here is my code:

```java
static boolean RekPier(int tab[][], int i, int j, int m, int n, int k){

        System.out.println(i + " " + j + " " + tab[i][j]);

        if (tab[i][j] == k && i < m && j < n){
            findex = i;
            lindex = j;
            return true;
        }

        else if((tab[i][j] > k || tab[i][n-1] < k) && (i < m && j < n)){

            int i1 = i+1;

            if(i1 == m) return false;

            RekPier(tab, i1, 0, m, n, k);
        }

        else if (i < m && j < n){

            int j1 = j+1;

            if(j1 == n) return false;

            RekPier(tab, i, j1, m, n, k);
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Just calling `RekPier` is meaningless. Try to `return RekPier(...);`.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation had some errors but i modified the function like so:

```
static int RekPier(int arr[][], int i, int j,int M ,int N,int Value)
{
    // If the entire column is traversed
    if (j >= M)
        return 0;

    // If the entire row is traversed
    if (i >= N)
        return 1;

    if(arr[i][j] == Value){
        System.out.println("Row:" +i +'\t' +"Column:" +j);
    }

    // Recursive call to traverse the matrix in the Horizontal direction
    if (RekPier(arr, i,j + 1, M, N,Value) == 1)
        return 1;

    // Recursive call for changing the Row of the matrix
    return RekPier(arr,i + 1,0, M, N,Value);
}
```

Same complexity as yours